# How to correctly set the current time stamp into this Java CRUD method that insert a value into a MySql table?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, timestamp

I have the following table into a MySql database:

```
CREATE TABLE log(
    timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    action ENUM('addPerson', 'getPerson', 'getPeople', 'updatePerson', 'deletePerson', 'deleteAll') NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (timestamp)
);
```

Now I am implementing a JAVA **insert** CRUD method into a DAO but I am finding some problem setting the **timestamp** value (initialized with the current date time) into the related prepared statment.

So I am doing something like this:

```
public void addEntry(String message) throws SQLException {
    // The Connection object is a singleton and the used connection is the same for all the CRUD methods:
    Connection conn = Database.getInstance().getConnection();

    PreparedStatement p = conn.prepareStatement("insert into log (timestamp, action) values (?,?)");

    p.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(time));
}
```

but it gime men error on the creation of the **Timestamp** object because it need a **long** value. So I think that this is not what I would !!!

How can I set it to the current timestamp (the current date-time)?

Tnx

Comment: Try this: `p.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));`

Comment: Duplicate of: [*Timestamp from the client or the server - What's the best practice?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56531013/642706)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `p.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));`

Note: I'd recommend you to check Javadoc before posting on SO. It really helps.

Comment: The terrible `java.sql.Timestamp` class is now legacy, supplanted by the modern *java.time* class `java.time.OffsetDateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible `java.sql.Timestamp` class. Specifically, JDBC 4.2 and later supports [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) for this.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Write to database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieve.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

[image]

## `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Even better, automate. Use `DEFAULT` on the definition of the table to automatically capture the current moment while inserting the row. For details on both standard SQL as well as MySQL syntax, see [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56531931/642706).